# Change default python distribution for postgres from the system's python (to Enthought Canopy)

Tags: python, postgresql

On an RHEL6 system, I'd like my postGIS implementation (ie my postgres/postgresql databases) to use Enthought's Canopy distribution of python, rather than the built-in GNU's distribution. (This is because postGIS needs some packages that seem hard to install from RHEL's built-in repositories.)

How can I change the python path / etc just for postgres?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods to try.

#### Override stop/start script

In the stop/start script for PostgresSQL I would add the path to this custom version of Python. The start/stop script is here, for example: `/etc/init.d/postgresql`. If you add a line towards the top of this script:

```
export PATH=/path/to/postGIS/python:$PATH
```

You'll override the location that Python is used from.

#### Add a customization vis sysconfig

Most Red Hat services will look in the directory `/etc/sysconfig` for additional customizations. You could try adding the custom `PATH` there instead.

Create a file like this: `/etc/sysconfig/pgsql/mycustompath.bash`, and add the following line to it (you might need other entries as well):

```
export PATH=/path/to/postGIS/python:$PATH
```

#### References

- [PostgreSQL on RedHat Linux](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_on_RedHat_Linux)